# On the order of the head of product of two simple modules over Quiver Hecke Algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, geometric-representation-theory, hecke-algebras, klr-algebras

My question is:

We assume the underlying quiver is a Dynkin quiver. Let $L(\lambda)$ and $L(\mu)$ be two simple modules over Quiver Hecke algebra $R$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two Konstant partitions with condition $\lambda\succ \mu$. This order is deduced from one ordering of positive roots. If one of them is real simple module. We denote $L(\lambda*\mu)$ as the head of $L(\lambda)\circ L(\mu)$.

Is it true that $\lambda*\mu$ is the largest element in the Konstant partitions of simple modules appearing in the filtration of $L(\lambda)\circ L(\mu)$?

**Motivation**:
Since Kashiwara and his coauthors show that there is a cluster structure on a subcategory of $R$-gmod. But I think the cluster structure on quantum nilpotent algebras is independent on its categorifications. Thus, there must be to exist a combination property for this cluster structure.